# Not getting output while trying db.find() in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Recently i have started learning mongodb and started to make a simple application that will just display the data present in my database.
Here's the code:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/new_app",{ useNewUrlParser: true });

var familySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    age:Number,
    gender:String   
});

var family = mongoose.model("family", familySchema);
family.create({
    name: "Test", age: 17, gender: "Male"
},function(err,member){
    if(member){
        console.log("Added Successfully");
    }
});

family.find({}, function(err,members){
    if(members){
        console.log(members);
    }       
});
```

After running this code, the data successfully gets stored in the database but it didn't show me the output of all the data in my database.
Can anyone explain how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the data gets added successfully, if so does it shows up in the respective MongoDB console maybe Robo3T, your code seems right to me

Comment: Try logging the error

Comment: yes..it's showing in the mongo console...but not in the js file itself.

Comment: It is just showing an empty array..but showing data in the mongodb console

Comment: Could you specify something more like if the db is connected properly or not, there seems no problem with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node uses non-blocking I/O and an asynchronous event-driven mode, so you should using `async/await`

```
const { func } = require("joi");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/new_app2",{ useNewUrlParser: true });

var familySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    age:Number,
    gender:String   
});

var family = mongoose.model("family", familySchema);
async function run() {
    await family.create({name: "Test", age: 17, gender: "Male"})
    let result  = await family.find({})
    console.log(result)
  }

  run()
```